# starting container process caused "exec: \"/app\": permission denied": unknown

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux

When I was trying to build golang using docker

The image build of docker was successful, but the following error occurred when running with docker run

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/app\": permission denied": unknown.
```

I think this error cause no user add, so I added group and user as below

```
RUN groupadd -g 10001 myapp \
    && useradd -u 10001 -g myapp myapp
```

but didn't fix.

Here is my source docker file

```
FROM golang:1.12.9 as builder

ADD . /go/src/appname/

WORKDIR /go/src/appname/

ENV GO111MODULE=on

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download
COPY . .

RUN  CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 make build target=prod

FROM alpine

RUN apk update \
  && apk add --no-cache

COPY --from=builder /go/src/ /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app" ]
```

thanks

Comment: your entryporint is a folder therefore you got `permission denied` try to set it to real executable ....

Comment: If your binary is located on the docker at `/app`, then after you copy it, try enabling execution rights on it with this command: `RUN chmod +x /app`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are copying your entire source folder into the directory `/app` in this step:

```
COPY --from=builder /go/src/ /app
```

Then you try to execute the directory:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app" ]
```

Instead, you need to copy the compiled binary that your go build outputs in the copy step.

Comment: @jadejoe, this answer (specifically, its final line of English text) is telling you to do the exact same thing you say [in your new self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57856471/14122) fixed the issue. Why add that new answer, and not just accept this one?

Comment: @Charles Duffy ,That is true.

It became an important hint.
I actually wrote my answer because I needed to show the golang binary correctly.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the output directory to your binary.

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -o /app .
```

then copy the app directory

```
COPY --from=builder /app ./
RUN chmod +x ./app
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the advice of everyone, I fix this issue

I couldn't just COPY with the build binary properly specified

before

```
COPY --from=builder /go/src/ /app
```

after

```
COPY --from=builder /go/src/build/build_app_name /app
```

thanks!!